# Wrapping inner XML nodes with an outer node in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Take the following TSQL

```
SELECT 
    o.id as '@id',
    (SELECT 
         op.id as '@orderid'
     FROM 
         Orders o
     INNER JOIN 
         OrderParts op ON o.id = op.orderId
     FOR XML PATH ('orderpart'), TYPE)
FROM 
    Orders o
FOR XML PATH ('order'), ROOT('application')
```

Generated from these tables.

**Orders**

```
Id   type
----------------
1    Pending
2    Active
```

**Order Parts**

```
id   orderid
-------------
1       1
2       1
3       3
4       2
```

It generates this XML

```
<application>
  <order id="1">
    <orderpart orderid="1" />
    <orderpart orderid="2" />
    <orderpart orderid="3" />
    <orderpart orderid="4" />
  </order>
  <order id="2">
    <orderpart orderid="1" />
    <orderpart orderid="2" />
    <orderpart orderid="3" />
    <orderpart orderid="4" />
  </order>
</application>
```

How do I add outer plural tags using TSQL around orders and orderparts so that it looks like the following?

```
<application>
  <orders>
    <order id="1">
      <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderid="1" />
        <orderpart orderid="2" />
        <orderpart orderid="3" />
        <orderpart orderid="4" />
      </orderparts>
    </order>
    <order id="2">
      <orderparts>
        <orderpart orderid="1" />
        <orderpart orderid="2" />
        <orderpart orderid="3" />
        <orderpart orderid="4" />
      </orderparts>
    </order>
  </orders>
</application>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(
     SELECT o.id AS '@id',
     (
          SELECT op.id as '@orderid'
          FROM OrderParts op 
          WHERE op.orderID = o.ID
          FOR XML PATH ('orderpart'), TYPE
     ) AS 'OrderParts'
     FROM Orders o
     FOR XML PATH ('order'),TYPE
 )
 FOR XML PATH ('orders'),ROOT('application')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, looks like this is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close - just add and/or tweak a few column aliases here and there...

```
SELECT 
    o.id as 'order/@id',
    (SELECT 
         op.id as '@orderid'
     FROM 
         Orders o
     INNER JOIN 
         OrderParts op ON o.id = op.orderId
     FOR XML PATH ('orderpart'), TYPE) AS 'order/orderparts'
FROM 
    Orders o
FOR XML PATH ('orders'), ROOT('application')
```

and that should do it! :-)

Comment: That's really close but I get multiple <orders> tags with that query.  I need just one <orders> tag like in my example.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders(Id INT,[type] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Orders
SELECT 1,    'Pending'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'Active'

CREATE TABLE [#Order Parts](Id INT,orderid INT)

INSERT INTO [#Order Parts]
SELECT 1,   1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   2
```

**QUERY**

**1. Using all possibilities for each Id(Your expected output)**

```
;WITH CTE(orderid,orderpartid) AS
(
    SELECT ODR.id orderid ,ODRP.Id orderpartid
    FROM #Orders ODR
    CROSS JOIN [#Order Parts] ODRP 
)
,CTE2 AS
(
   -- This SELECT is used to name the xml data column
    select 
    (
        -- We take orders as the root node
        select t1.orderid as 'order/@Id',
        (
            SELECT T.orderpartid '@orderid' 
            FROM CTE T
            WHERE T.orderid=t1.orderid
            FOR XML PATH('orderpart'), type
        )as 'order/orderparts' 
        from    CTE t1
        group by t1.orderid
        for xml path(''), root('orders')
    )XMLDATA    
)
-- We take application as the root node for orders
select CAST(XMLDATA AS XML)
FROM CTE2
for xml path('application')
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36487b/1) to view result**

**RESULT**

[image]

**2. Select matching elements for each Id**

```
;WITH CTE(orderid,orderpartid) AS
(
    SELECT ODR.id orderid ,ODRP.Id orderpartid
    FROM #Orders ODR
    JOIN [#Order Parts] ODRP ON ODR.id = ODRP.orderId
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    select 
    (
        select t1.orderid as 'order/@Id',
        (
            SELECT T.orderpartid '@orderid' 
            FROM CTE T
            WHERE T.orderid=t1.orderid
            FOR XML PATH('orderpart'), type
        )as 'order/orderparts' 
        from    CTE t1
        group by t1.orderid
        for xml path(''), root('orders')
    )XMLDATA    
)
select CAST(XMLDATA AS XML)
FROM CTE2
for xml path('application')
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36487b/2) to view result**

**RESULT**

[image]